# Richfaces ExtendedDataTable customization of groupings output

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm looking to implement the ExtendedDataTable component in Richfaces.

When selecting the 'Group by' on a column, I would like to have a 'Select all' option displayed on each grouping row. This would select/un-select all checkboxes under this grouping.

I dont think there is any quick easy solution to this?
Would I need to extend the ExtendedDataTable base class somehow to add this functionality?

**Edit:** I got [this response](http://community.jboss.org/message/587235#587235) from the Richfaces team.

Has anybody created their own `ExtendedDataTable` based on the `ExtendedDataTable` implementation?
Is it difficult? Time consuming?

Even if somebody created a custom `DataTable` or other component, could you offer some advice or tips?

Here are [the component creation documents](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/).